# Create function that merges two datasets based on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

One large with 3 object columns (ex. Client, Region, Type) and a smaller dataframe with the same 3 columns as well as a quantity that I am trying to merge to the large df. Like a lookup.

What would be a function that takes the large dataframe row and determines what the qty is for each row based on matching of the 3 object columns?

Code example:

```
def quantity(row):
   if row['Client'] == 'clientA':
       if (row['Region'] in ['west']) & (row['Type'] in ['low']):
           return 0
       else:
           if (row['Client'] in ['east']) & (row['Type'] in ['high']):
               return 0.4
           else:
               return 0.5
```

This works however I want to make the 0, 0.4, and 0.5 not hardcode but instead pulling those values from the other small dataframe

Comment: The issue I get when using a simple merge (how-left) is that all the merged quantities become nan

Comment: Please include an example and your code.

Comment: This seems like a straightforward use of join (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html); is it not working? Please include an example of what happens when you try this.

Answer (score 0):

Merge the large dataframe with the small one. To keep all rows of the large dataframe, use the `how="left"` parameter:

```
df_large = df_large.merge(df_small, how="left")
```

---

To verify it, let

```
df_large
```

> ```
>      Client   Region   Type
> 0   clientA     west    low
> 1   clientA     east   high
> 2   clientB     east    low
> 3   clientB    north   high
> 4   clientB    south    low
> 5   clientC     west   high
> ```

and

```
df_small
```

> ```
>      Client   Region   Type  quantity
> 0   clientB    north   high        10
> 1   clientA     east   high         2
> ```

Then

```
df_large.merge(df_small, how="left")
```

> ```
>      Client   Region   Type  quantity
> 0   clientA     west    low       NaN
> 1   clientA     east   high       2.0
> 2   clientB     east    low       NaN
> 3   clientB    north   high      10.0
> 4   clientB    south    low       NaN
> 5   clientC     west   high       NaN
> ```